# Multisite Wordpress DNS Records

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, internationalization, multisite

I'm setting up a webshop at example.nl and I have bought another domain (example.com) which I intend to use for the English version of my webshop. I've set up a wordpress multisite to accomplish this, but I'm stuck. My goal is to set up as follows: NL = example.nl, EN = example.com, DE = example.com/de/. Right now the international websites, nor their wordpress dashboards are accessible, I think this has to do with the DNS records. What should I change in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can choose different URL formats when building a multilingual website.

**1. ccTLDs: Country Code top-level Domains**
example.es (Spain)
example.de (Germany)

**2. gTLDs: Subdomains with generic top-level domains**
es.example.com
it.example.org

**3. gTLDs: Subdirectories with Generic top-level domains**
example.com/es/
example.com/en/

You need to use plugins like [WPML](https://wplang.org/plugins/wpml) and [Wordpress MU Domain Mapping](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

[WPML Multi Domain Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DHU4.jpg)

[Worpress MU Domain Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIEm6.jpg)

> Earlier in 2016, I used subdomain format for my categories:
>   example.com/category/food output was like; food.example.com and it was
>   a successful implementation with wp plugn+dns,wildcard settings.